# Why does splitting eliminate part of the String in this c# code?

Tags: c#, regex, split

I am parsing text and if I encounter a time, I want to split the string. Here is an example:

```
At 12:30AM I got up. At 11:30PM I went to bed.
```

My code :

```
string time = @"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(A|P)M";
string test = "At 12:30AM I got up. At 11:30PM I went to bed.";
string[] result = Regex.Split(test, time);

foreach(string element in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

What I need to get:

```
At 12:30AM
I got up. At 11:30PM
I went to bed.
```

What I get:

```
At
 A
  I got up. At
 P
  I went to bed.
```

All that is left of the times are either A or P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex to

```
([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[AP]M)
```

Thhe brackets around (A|P) are defining it as the capture group. You need the the whole time string to be captured. So put the brackets around the whole thing.

Comment: Doesn't `[A|P]` match `A`, `|`, and `P`?

Comment: `|` is a special character. So it won't be matched unless it comes with an escape character.

Comment: Ohhk.. New to regex... changed!

Comment: Thanks guys, all the answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Because the split function separator is not included in the results.
If you want it to remain as a split element enclose it in parenthesis

```
string time = @"([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(A|P)M)";
```

By the way, that's the reason that the 'A' and 'P' were left, because they were enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: Indeed; you want to use [AP] or (?:A|P) if you don't want to capture A or P on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups.

```
string regex=@".+?(?:\b\d{2}:\d{2}(?:AM|PM)|$)";
MatchCollection matches=Regex.Matches(input,regex);
foreach(var match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0]);
```

Comment: -1. You really should test your solutions before you post them.  All those forward slashes in the regex should be backslashes, the `MatchesCollection` class name should be `MatchCollection`, and you should be calling the `Matches` method instead of `Match`.  And when you've fixed all that, it still won't do what the OP wants.

Comment: You're right about the fixes, but the final thing WILL do what the asker wants, or at least what he wrote. He want to include the words before the pattern, as seen in his example.

Comment: 'Fraid not.  You left the semicolon off the first line and you've got the arguments to `Matches()` reversed.  That's why you should always test before posting, even if you're totally confident in the *logic* of your answer.  But your regex still isn't right, as you can see [**here**](http://ideone.com/zN47KG).  Maybe you're thinking of [**this**](http://ideone.com/shiPH2)?

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Thanks for correcting me. The site looks pretty cool...